# CallOut Function Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm building three line graphs in d3.js and I would like that when the viewer hovers over a section of the line graph, they are able to see the country, date and incidents. Currently all that is being returned is an undefined. any help would be immensely appreciated.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="callOut">
<div id="divCountry"></div>
<div id="divDate"></div>
<div id="divIncidents"></div>
</div>
```

Here are my helper functions:

```
function circleHover(chosen) {

if (modus == "incidents") {

d3.select("#callOut")
  .style("top", "570px")
  .style("left", "30px"); 


d3.select("#divCountry").html('Country: ' + chosen.country);
d3.select("#divDate").html('Date: ' + chosen.date);
d3.select("#divIncidents").html('Incidents: ' + chosen.incidents);


d3.select("#callOut")
.style("visibility","visible");

}
}; 

function showOne(d) {


var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

var incidentsData = svg.append("g"); 

incidentsData.selectAll(".incidentsData")
            .data(incidentData)
            .enter()
            .append('incidentsData')
            .attr('class', 'incidentsData');

var chosen = d;
var setOpacity = 0;

if (modus == "incidents") {
  circleHover(chosen);
  setOpacity = 0.1;

  incidentsData.selectAll(".incidentsData")
 .filter(function (d) { return eval("d.country") != 
 eval("chosen.country");})
 .style("fill-opacity", setOpacity);
}

}
};
```

Here is a snapshot of my incidentsData:

```
var incidentData = 
[
{
"country": "Israel",
"date": 1971,
"incidents": 1,
"": ""
},
{
"country": "Israel",
"date": 1972,
"incidents": 15,
"": ""
},
```

Here is my totalIncidentsLineGraph:

```
function totalIncidentsLineGraph() {

modus = "incidents"; 


var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

var incidentsData = svg.append("g"); 

incidentsData.selectAll(".incidentsData")
            .data(incidentData)
            .enter()
            .append('incidentsData')
            .attr('class', 'incidentsData')
            .attr('id', function(d) { return d.country, d.date, 
             d.incidents}); 

 var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse; 

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-height).tickSubdivide(true),
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("right");


var area = d3.svg.area()
.interpolate("monotone")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.incidents); }); 

var line = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("monotone")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.incidents); });

function type(d) {
d.country = d.country;
d.date = parse(d.date);
d.incidents = +d.incidents
return d;
};

var data = d3.csv("static/data/israel/incidents_linechart.csv", type, 
function(error, data) {
console.log(data);

var israel = data.filter(function(d) {
return d.country == "Israel";
});

var unitedStates = data.filter(function(d) {
return d.country == "United States";
});

var iran = data.filter(function(d) {
return d.country == "Iran";
});

x.domain([unitedStates[0].date, unitedStates[unitedStates.length - 
1].date]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(egypt, function(d) { return d.incidents; 
})]).nice();

 var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + 
   ")")


svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);


 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("id", "titleLine")
      .attr("y", -50)
      .attr("x", 250)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("font-size", "12px")
      .text("Total Incidents Amongst Countries: 1970 - 2017"); 

 var colors = d3.scale.category10();

  svg.selectAll('.line')
.data([israel, unitedStates, iran, saudiArabia, turkey, egypt, syria, 
lebanon, jordan, palestine]) /// can add however many i want here 
.enter()
  .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .style('stroke', function(d) {
      return colors(Math.random() * 50);
    })
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return line(d);
    })
  .on("mouseover", showOne)
  .on("mouseout", showAll);
```

Comment: How are you  calling showOne() ? My guess is that `d` is not what you think it is.

Comment: @BrunoFenzi thank you so much  for responding. I just added my linegraph function above with the showOne() function inside of it.

Comment: There's a lot going on in your snippets. Without a minimal working example -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I guess I cant help much.